# Visual Studio 2010 complains about a missing DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I created a project which should use a thirdparty library. I specified the include path and the linker path of the include and lib files respectively. I added all the libraries (.lib files) in Linker-->Input under Project Properties. Everything is now compiling and linking well, but when I start my program it is complaining that a dll is missing. I checked in the lib folder and the dll is there. So, now I do not understand how VS2010 could complain about this. Copying the dll in the project folder solves the problem. But I do not want to copy all the dlls i need in my project folder. Is there a solution here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the .dll folders to your projects Properties > Debbuging > Environment, like

```
PATH=C:\PATH_TO_SOMETHING\DLL;%PATH%
```

Answer (score -1):

i typically copy all third party dll's to the bin folder in my project using windows explorer.  Then just add a reference to each one in vs.   All referenced dll's end up in you bin folder anyways, even when it is compiled and published.

That way I have all my third party dll's for my project in one place.  It feels cleaner that way especially when you backup, move or copy projects on different servers, hard drives, computers, etc.

[image]

Comment: a dialog will appear, go to the "Browse" section and just browse to the bin folder in your project to reference your dll

Comment: But if I go under Project->References... and then click on add new reference, a dialog appears with nothing in it and there is no possibility to add anything...

Comment: You should see a bunch of tabs in the dialog.   You have to click the Browse tab.  I will post a screen shot

Comment: You need to copy all your project 3RD PARTY dll's into the bin folder in your project from windows explorer or else you will not see any dlls like shown in my screen shot

Comment: I think know why.  Its actually under "Website"-->Add Reference.  I was looking at VS 2012 instead of 2010

Comment: Do you see a bin folder in your project?

Comment: what kind of project is it (web forms, win forms, wpf,etc)?

Comment: yes, I basically created an empty c++ project and then added c++ and header files

Comment: I would try copying all the dll's into that bin folder and compiling and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Of course I can leave my dlls there, but it would be nice to organize the structure of course..

Comment: I found a previous post says, make sure your .dll/.lib file(s) are in the same directory as the .exe/.dll you are building and then go to your project's "Solution Explorer", right-click on the project name, choose "Add" -> "Existing Item...", then select the .dll/.lib file you want to include.

You should now see the .dll/.lib file listed below the "Source Files" section in the "Solution Explorer".

Comment: Another solution was to convert the .lib into a .dll as this might be a quark with vs 2012 and c++ projects